# Squash Git commits *non-interactively* with git rebase

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-rebase

I am looking for a way to squash commits with git rebase, but non-interactively. My question is, can we use git merge-base to find the common ancestor to "merge down to" and then squash all commits that are not shared?

E.g.:

```
git init
# make changes
git add . && git commit -am "first"
git checkout -b dev
# make changes to dev 
# *(in the meantime, someone else makes changes to remote master)*
git add . && git commit -am "second"
SHARED=$(git merge-base dev master)
git rebase ${SHARED}
```

above, because no changes to master happened in the meantime, I am not sure if this script would do anything. But what it definitely will **not** do, is squash commits. Is there anyway I can somehow squash all commits made on the dev branch, that are not in master?

Maybe the best thing to do would be to rebase, and then follow it with:

```
git reset --soft ${SHARED}
```

The `reset --soft` command should squash commits

To be clear, here is what I am looking for:

1. clean linear history given by git rebase
2. squash commits from feature branch without unnecessary interactivity

`git rebase -i` uses interactivity, which I want to avoid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will plop the `dev` tree into a new commit on `master` (note: this is *not* equivalent to a rebase, as @torek kindly points out below):

```
git checkout dev         && \
git reset --soft master  && \
git commit
```

Note that you should not have uncommitted pages or untracked files when doing this.

Here's how it works:

1. `checkout dev` will update `HEAD`, your index (staging area), and working tree to match the state of the repository at `dev`,
2. `reset --soft master` will not affect your index or working tree (which means that all the files in your staging area will reflect exactly the state of the repository at `dev`), but will point `HEAD` at `master`, and
3. `commit` will commit your index (which corresponds to `dev`) and walk `master` forward.

The `&&`s ensure that the script does not continue if anything fails.

Comment: cool thanks; I think you could run the rebase after reset --soft?

Comment: Why do you want to `rebase`? This is equivalent to `rebase -i`, `2,$s/pick/squash/ | wq`. Also, if you do try to `rebase` after `reset --soft master` all you're going to be doing is trying to rebase `master` onto `master`, which is instantly going to fail if `dev` has diverged in any way because you have a dirty index.

Comment: Well rebase makes for a cleaner/simpler history. Maybe I could rebase before doing reset --soft instead of after?

Comment: There is literally no difference between what I've suggested here and `git rebase`, unless you're thinking about what's happening to the reflog.

Comment: git rebase does not squash commits unless you use the -i flag, that's the difference right? reset --soft will squash commits with the need for interactivity. I want to rebase to get the clean linear history, and I want to squash commits and I don't want to use the -i flag if I don't have to. The only way to do this is to use reset --soft in conjunction with git rebase. Right? The question is: how to use them in conjunction?

Comment: It remains incredibly unclear what you want to do. You can either `rebase` to replay all divergent commits starting from the merge-base or `reset --soft && commit` (`rebase -i` if interactivity is OK) to squash the commits.

Comment: Np, I understand it's confusing - I updated the question with the two things I am looking for - so far I have had luck with *git rebase master* followed by *git reset --soft master*. This seems to do what I want, if that makes sense.

Comment: I think what you might be confused about is that in my example master hasn't changed, but actually I am assuming master *has* changed while I was making changed to dev branch. I will update the question. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

#### Doing this with `git merge --squash`

I answered this below with a method using `git rebase` first, and then a subsequent `git reset --soft ... && git commit` sequence.  See that part of this answer for details.  However, you can do all the "rebase-and-squash" work in a single Git command, because `git merge --squash` does what you want: it performs the *action of merging* (merge as a verb), without making *a merge* (merge as a noun: a *merge commit*).   (You still need a few extra setup and finish commands—there is a total of five commands, in the end, unless you want to try it as a script.<sup>2</sup>)

Let's start with a sample input graph:

```
...--o--*---------Z   <-- master
         \
          A--B--C     <-- dev
```

Now, your end goal—see the other section for details—looks like this:

```
...--o--*---------Z      <-- master
         \         \
          \         D    <-- dev
           \
            A--B--C      [abandoned]
```

where commit `D` is, in effect, what you get if you turn the `A--B--C` sequence into a *changeset* to apply to commit `*`, then apply that changeset, using three-way-merge, to commit `Z` with `*` as its *merge base*.  This, of course, is just what a regular `git merge` would do.

The problem is that a regular merge would make a *merge commit*, giving:

```
...--o--*---------Z
         \         \
          \         D
           \       /
            A--B--C
```

We *do* want commit `D`, but we want `D` to be an *ordinary*, single-parent, commit.  This is where `git merge --squash` shines.  This is precisely what `git merge --squash` *does*: it merges (verb) but then makes an ordinary commit—or rather, makes *us* make the commit (we have to run our own `git commit` command).

We also want something else, though: we want `D` to be the tip commit of branch `dev`, with branch `master` not moved.  I carefully filed off the branch *names* from the merge graph above, because if we did a regular merge the regular way, we'd do it while being on branch `master`, and commit `D` would then wind up on branch `master`.  That's *not* what we want.

Now, there is a very simple rule `git commit` uses when making a new commit: the new commit goes on the *current branch*.  So, assuming the merge is already done but there's no commit yet, how can we get Git to make the new commit `D` on the correct branch, i.e., on `dev`?  Well, we can't.<sup>1</sup>  Instead, we should make this squash-merge commit `D` on a *temporary branch*.

We start by checking out commit `Z`, the tip of master, as a new temporary branch:

```
git checkout -b temp-for-squash master
```

Now we run `git merge --squash dev`, to set up our index with the merge result that will become commit `D`:

```
git merge --squash dev
```

Now we commit the result, because `--squash` implies `--no-commit`:

```
git commit
```

The result at this point looks like this:

```
...--o--*---------Z      <-- master
         \         \
          \         D    <-- temp-for-squash (HEAD)
           \
            A--B--C      <-- dev
```

Now all we have to do is make the label `dev` point to `temp-for-squash`, which is where we are now.  We *could* do this with `git checkout dev; git reset --hard temp-for-squash`, but we can do it in one step:

```
git branch -f dev HEAD
```

I have deliberately used the name `HEAD` here, because—well, look at where we used the name `temp-for-squash`.  We used it just once, in the `git checkout` command.  And, now that we've moved `dev`, we don't *need* the `temp-for-squash` name any more.  So let's not use it at all—let's change the `git checkout` above to:

```
git checkout --detach master
```

to get a "detached HEAD".  Everything else works as before, because a detached HEAD acts as an *anonymous* branch.  The new commit we make, when we run `git commit` after `git merge --squash`, makes commit `D` on this unnamed branch, updating `HEAD`.  Then we use `git branch -f dev` to move `dev`.

Last, we probably want to run `git checkout dev`, so that we are on the `dev` branch (but we can `git checkout` any branch name you like now).  Hence, the final command sequence is:

```
git checkout --detach master
git merge --squash dev
git commit
git branch -f dev HEAD
git checkout dev
```

The advantage to doing this, over doing the two-part "first `git rebase`, then `git reset`" sequence is that when you *do* rebase, and it copies a chain of commits, you may get merge conflicts on *each* copied commit.  If so, you will probably get a merge conflict on the squash merge too—but with the squash merge, you will have one big conflict to resolve once, instead of many small conflicts to resolve one commit at a time.

This is also the *dis*advantage to doing this.  It may be easier to resolve many small conflicts, one commit at a time.  Or it may be easier to resolve one big conflict once.  It's your repository, and these are your commits; you get to decide.

---

<sup>1</sup>There are actually at least two ways to do it, but all of them involve various kinds of cheating: using commands that are meant for scripts.  The simplest is to use `git symbolic-ref` to rewrite `HEAD` directly.  I'll mention it here but leave working out the details, i.e., why this works, as an exercise:

```
git checkout --detach master
git merge --squash dev
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/dev
git commit
```

There is a second method in the next footnote.

<sup>2</sup>Here's an **untested** script that takes just one parameter, which is the branch on which to rebase-and-squash.  To use the script you must be *on* the branch you intend to rebase-and-squash, i.e., `dev`.  This does a bit of cheating and the previous value of the `dev` head will be just `ORIG_HEAD` rather than `dev@{1}`, because we update `dev` a few times, and if the merge needs assistance, we'll force the user (i.e., you) to do the `git commit`.

Note: I use `git-sh-setup` for various functions, such as `die` and `require_clean_work_tree`.  This means you must invoke this script with the `git` front end, i.e., place it somewhere in your `$PATH`, named `git-rebase-and-squash`, then run `git rebase-and-squash`.

```
#! /bin/sh

self="rebase-and-squash"

. git-sh-setup

[ $# = 1 ] || die "usage: $self <branch-or-commit>"

require_clean_work_tree $self

source=$(git rev-parse HEAD) || exit 1
target=$(peel_commitish "$1") || exit 1

# Everything looks OK.  Set ORIG_HEAD, then move current branch
# to target commit.  We'll rely on ORIG_HEAD to protect the chain.
set_reflog_action $self
git update-ref ORIG_HEAD $source
gut reset --hard $target
if git merge --squash $current_branch; then
    # merge succeeded without assistance: do the commit
    git commit
else
    status=$?
    echo "merge failed - finish the merge and run 'git commit',"
    echo "or use 'git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD' to abort."
    exit $status
fi
```

#### Doing this with `git rebase` and `git reset --soft`

[Pockets' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42333350/1256452) is correct (and upvoted) for the case you originally described.  You may need an explanation, though, especially since the arguments to the various commands may need a bit of tweaking in other setups, such as the more general case you seem to be aiming for.

> I am looking for a way to squash commits with git rebase ...

All `git rebase` does is copy commits, then move the current branch label to point to the last-copied commit.  There's no reason you have to use `git rebase` itself to do these steps, although for some cases, it will be easier.

> but non-interactively. My question is, can we use git merge-base to find the common ancestor to "merge down to" and then squash all commits that are not shared?

Yes.

Your necessary steps, which are those performed *by* `git rebase`, are:

- find the merge base or otherwise identify the commit(s) to copy;
- do whatever copying you wish; and
- move the branch label accordingly.

To understand the actions (and hence commands) we need, start by *drawing the graph* (or the interesting part of it):

```
...--o--*           <-- master
         \
          A--B--C   <-- dev
```

Here, the name `master` points to the merge base commit.  (I'm using a slight variant of the `git init; ...` sequence you showed above, here, with an existing repository with at least one commit *before* the merge base commit.)  Let's make this graph a bit more interesting by making a *new* commit on `master`, though:

```
...--o--*--Z        <-- master
         \
          A--B--C   <-- dev
```

You may want your *graph*, in the end, to look like this:

```
...--o--*--Z        <-- master
         \
          D         <-- dev
```

where `D` is the result of combining `A-B-C`, as `git rebase -i` would do if you changed all but the first `pick` to `squash` while rebasing onto the merge base commit `*`.

Note that the *saved snapshot* for this new commit `D`, with its new commit message (whatever that is), is the *same* as the saved snapshot for commit `C`.  That is, combining `A-B-C` is essentially the same as *forgetting* `A` and `B` graph-wise, while keeping the *code* they introduced, so that the tree for `D` matches the tree for `C`.

Now, *if there is no commit `Z` on `master`*, you can do this with Pockets' answer.  The reason is that if you are sitting on commit `C`, with the index and work-tree matching that for `C`, and you do:

```
git reset --soft master
```

this will retain the index and work-tree as is, but change the *graph* to read:

```
...--o--*           <-- dev (HEAD), master
         \
          A--B--C   [abandoned]
```

When you then run `git commit`, you will make a new commit on `dev`, which will be commit `D`:

```
...--o--*           <-- master
         \
          D         <-- dev
```

and you are now done.  But if there *is* a new commit `Z`, things change.

If you want:

```
...--o--*--Z        <-- master
         \
          D      <-- dev
```

then the trick is to `git reset -soft` to the merge base commit `*`, and otherwise do the same thing.  But if you want:

```
...--o--*--Z        <-- master
            \
             D      <-- dev
```

then you need considerably more work.

In this case, the simplest solution without writing any code is probably to `git rebase` (non-interactively) first to copy `A-B-C` to `A'-B'-C'` that descend from `Z`, giving:

```
...--o--*--Z        <-- master
            \
             A'-B'-C'  <-- dev
```

Now you can `git reset --soft master && git commit` as before, to make commit `D` from the index that `git rebase` made when it made commit `C'`.

Comment: well, Pocket was saying to use git reset --soft, which will help with squash. I was saying I still want to rebase for the normal reasons. I will have to read your answer a couple more times to fully grok it, but AFAICT what you saying is to *git rebase master* first and then *git reset --soft master* to do the squash afterward, with no interactivity necessarily required. ?

Comment: @torek the solution I suggested will work for squashing a feature branch even if `master` and `dev` have diverged.

Comment: agreed that if master hasn't changed, there is no need for rebase. in my code snippet above, I don't show that master has changed but I think I should add that assumption in the original question for clarity.

Comment: @Pockets yes, but I need to rebase too, that is the goal.

Comment: also, just to verify, if we do call git rebase master, but dev and master haven't diverged, there shouldn't be a problem, it's a essentially a no-op, is that correct?

Comment: @AlexanderMills: yes, a rebase that observes that no commits need to be copied/moved, is just a no-op.

Comment: @Pockets: if you `git checkout dev && git reset --soft master && git commit`, in the situation where `dev`'s merge base is commit `*` that comes before commit `Z`, you will "lose `Z`'s changes" as the tree for new commit `D` will match that for original commit `C`, while the parent will be `Z`. Compare with the the post-rebase `C'` above, where `A-B-C` were turned into patches that were applied atop `D`, so that they start from `D`'s tree as their base.

Comment: (Let me add a side note as well: you can apply `--no-ff` to *force* `git rebase` to copy commits where the rebase would normally be a no-op. This is meant for re-copying a branch that was merged, and then the merge was reverted. See https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt for details. That doesn't matter here, it's just a useful thing to keep in mind if you ever get into that situation.)

Comment: @torek I just facepalmed at myself - I completely agree with you now and have amended my original answer to reflect that. It so happens that I have a use case for the answer I suggested and at some point I managed to confuse in my head squashing a patch series with just wholesale dropping another Git tree on top of a branch.